# Better approach to convert Future to Boolean

Tags: scala

I have a db query which returns a `Future[String]`, the implementation does not matter, but the signature is something like this:

```
def getTicketType(id: Long): Future[String] = {...}
```

And imagine I have a list of ids which i would want to retrieve ticket types from those ids. so something like this:

```
val listOfIds: List[Long] = ... (from somewhere else of the code)

val ticketTypesFuture: Future[List[String]] = Future.sequence(listOfIds.map(getTicketType))
```

So far so good, but there is another function, which is called within the main process, that HAS to return a `Boolean` or an `Option[Boolean]` value, since it's result is used in the main process which holds a gigantic for comprehension, combined of some `Either[Int, Option[JsValue]]`'s. The way I'm doing it right now (which I believe is the worst way of implementing such thing :) ), is this:

```
def thatFunction(): Boolean = {
  //  ... val listOfIds, ticketTypesFuture defined above
  var result = false // here is the nasty code :)
  val futureResult: Future[Boolean] = ticketTypesFuture.map { ticketTypes => 
    if (!ticketTypes.forall(someCondition)) {
      // some code which returns either true or false
    } else false
  }

  futureResult.omComplete {
    case Success(value) => result = value
    case _              => result = false
  }
  result
}
```

But there must be a better approach to do this, so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: As a note, I can convert the result to Either[_, _] like: `_ <- Some(thatBooleanResult).find(x => x).toRight(someDefaultLeftValue)`, and the compiler would be happy and pleased

Comment: That var combined with a Future context is a disaster. You do not need var result. Could you post the entire code?

Comment: @joesan, of course, as I mentioned, that is probably the worst implementation :). I'm actually looking for a way to convert this Future[Boolean] to Option[Boolean]

Comment: Could you refactor that worst implementation into a new function to keep things simple? I'm not able to grasp what you are actually doing. If it is about getting some data from the database and using that data to fetch some additional data form some other source, they probably you could refactor each of those as separate functions returning a Future and you can compose them later on in another function.

Comment: The problem is that the query returns a Future instance, so I actually have to convert Future to Option somehow, right?

Comment: You mean the database query? Why bother converting a Future to an Option while you can wrap the result still in a Future and hold it until the end of the world which probably is your controller layer where we need the result inside the Future

Comment: In the Process layer (on layer before service layer), the huge for-comprehension block exists, and there are like 25 other values that result into a Either[_, _], I need to put this code somewhere just between the for comprehension, I need to convert Future to Option right here, as you know each expression inside that for comprehension must return an Either[_, _], because it's flatmapped

Comment: A `Future` already **is** an `Option` (in a sense) so the conversion is simple if you accept that a `Future` that has yet to complete is `None`: `futureResult.value.map(t => t.isSuccess && t.get)`

Comment: @jwvh, sure, but as I see this, the difference is that Future needs time to complete, while Option is just an immutable (in this case) instance, and as you can see [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XOlF9qr8Qk6y4CqOjaWb3w), I've already done the same approach, but since that Future function needs some time to complete, when I try to do that, I get None as the result, also let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AminMal; That's my point. You have 3 options: 1-Get the current `value`. (`None` if not completed.) 2-`Await.result`, which is a terrible idea that defeats the whole purpose of the `Future`. 3-Handle it properly, which means everything that touches `futureResult` becomes a `Future`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the answers and comments, multiple approaches have been discussed, which include:

1- waiting for the Future to complete (using mutation, Await, ...) which are the worst of the approaches, so just don't do that :)

2- mapping on the value like this: `futureResult.value.map(t => t.isSuccess && t.get)`

and some other solutions.
As @jwh mentioned, another solution is to handle it properly, anything that touches futureResult becomes a Future!
But since I couldn't change all the calculations and functions inside that for comprehension, I placed this Future[Boolean] condition outside of the for loop, and everythin is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you **must** convert `Future[Boolean]` to `Option[Boolean]` then you need to wait for the `Future` using `Await.result`. This will throw an error if the `Future` fails, so wrap it in a `Try`.

```
val futureResult: Future[Boolean] = ???

Try(Await.result(futureResult, Duration.Inf)).toOption
```

But the better solution is to convert the calling code to accept a `Future` and avoid blocking.

Comment: You do not want to do that in a serious code.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at the Future class, and saw `find` method, I'll try the find method and if that did not work, I might just use this!

Answer (score 3):

The sane option is to go the other way and make your "gigantic for comprehension, combined of some `Either[Int, Option[JsValue]]`'s" work with futures. Wrap the part before and after the query using `Future.apply` or `Future.successful`, and you should be fine. Or if it contains other database/API accesses, make them return `Future` as well.

If you can't, your choice is:

1. use `Await.result` as in Tim's answer, which loses any benefit of futures. If you really want that, consider using a library which doesn't return a future in the first place. But this may be a placeholder until you switch.
2. use [`Future#value`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/concurrent/Future.html#value:Option%5Bscala.util.Try%5BT%5D%5D) if you want not to wait and just do something else if the result is not ready. For example you might show some old results, or an empty list until you get data.

(After writing this, I saw @jwvh already said basically the same in a comment, hopefully it still helps to have a more expanded version.)